# Adding Induction Cooktop Circuit

Tags: wiring, kitchens

The instructions say that "a 3-wire or 4-wire single phase 120/240 40amp" connection is required. In the four-wire diagram, the neutral is capped off (not used by the cooktop).

What awg do I need for a 40amp run?
Is my understanding correct that because it's two phases, each phase acts as the others "neutral" - which is why you only need two 120 legs and a ground?

Comment: Yes, lavishly covered here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4 with plenty of cheek for those Europeans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40 amp is minimum 8 gauge, can use larger if handy.

The cooktop does not seem to need/use neutral, so only two hots/lives and ground.

Is the cooktop plugged in or hardwired(connected directly to the panel)?

Wondering if the 120/240 is more to say it is for North American electrical system, than it will run well with only 120.

Comment: It's hardwired. Thank you!

Comment: When the wiring instructions say "Minimum circuit required", this is the circuit size I should be wiring for, yes?

Comment: @geudrik    Would like to know what else is said with  "Minimum circuit required" and what they mean.  Minimum wire gauge for a 40 amp circuit is 8 gauge.  Imagine the cooktop requires 40 amps, so there is no minimum/maximum.

Comment: @geudrik That is correct. The minimum size that will allow the cooktop to operate as designed.  If there was a larger size already  installed, like a 50 amp breaker and #6 AWG, that would be OK.

Comment: @crip659 that's all it said really, it just struck me as odd wording. Almost implying that larger would be better (from a cooktop performance perspective), but not required.

Comment: Just a concern if it bought online.  North America requires electrical devices to have a UL listing/mark.  There are a couple of other marks that are allowed.  A CE mark is not.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run #8 AWG CU for a 40 amp service. In your case, you could run 8/2 with ground and connect the black and white wires to the double pole 40 amp breaker. Then tape the white wire with black tape to designate that it's a hot line. If I was doing this, I'd run 8/3 with ground because while you don't need the neutral now, you might need it in the future. Leave it disconnected at both locations.

Comment: Appreciate the assist!